How to change Microsoft "Personal account" to a "Business" or "Work" account?
Microsoft's website are far from easy to use. Here are the pages I've logged into under foo@bar.com:

Base Account: https://account.microsoft.com/profile
Partner Portal: https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/v2/account-settings/organization/legalinfo (empty page)
https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/exp/enrollment/programselector/basicpartnernetwork/firmographic/options/101/1510 (no idea why it's taking me there)
Azure directory: https://portal.azure.com/#settings/directory

I've emailed Microsoft support and they are asking me for 3 things:

Tenant ID
MPN ID
Login ID

I don't know what any of those are, or where to find them.
My ultimate goal is to sign up for the Microsoft Partner Center, so I can use the AI Personal Voice tool. But I can't figure out why it keeps saying "you are logged in under a personal address, please use a work address".... I AM using a work address, foo@bar.com, not foo@gmail.com.
How can I register for the Microsoft Partner Center, using my business email address foo@bar.com, given it says I am logged in as foo@bar.com but it's a "personal" email?
Only ID I can find is my Azure subscription ID....

Possible duplicate of  Error logging in to a Microsoft account I'm already logged in to

That question doesn't answer "how do you change your email from personal to organization".

After 2 more hours I didn't find a way to convert personal to work.

Which of the following subscriptions do you currently login to using your work email foo@bar.com? Office 365, Microsoft Azure, or Microsoft Dynamics CRM? Alternatively, what makes foo@bar.com a "work" account in your eyes?

You can't convert a Microsoft free account to a work account or vice versa.
Resources:

Create a Microsoft for Business account
What is Partner Center?
Azure AI Personal Voice Overview
Try Azure for free

